# Azure functions without swagger

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Working on a new project and I was asked to assist in configure a azure functions/API. From my understanding you either need to build the project with swagger or OpenAPI config file in some way. Is this untrue ?

Can a C# program run an azure function without either of these implementations ? Using Azure functions V2+

Comment: Are you running into an issue? The main thing it usually needs is the local.settings.json file and Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: You don't need swagger/openAPI. it's optional.

Comment: @juunas no the project ran with v1 azure functions nuget package. Trying to update to v2 or v3 and call the azure function through a http trigger now

Comment: @CarlosLopez If you want to host your api in Azure function, you can directly implement it  without swagger. You just need to create some http triggers with different method. For more details, please refer to https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-restful-serverless-api-with-azure-functions-and-mongodb-6221cfd51a43 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api

Comment: @CarlosLopez Any update?

Comment: During development time Swagger can be used to quickly detect path colisions. From the context given this is what I assume the issue is. You don't need swagger at all for AZ functions, just make sure there is no path collision like two endpoints with GET items.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run Azure functions without those implementations ( OpenAPI/Swagger).

You may follow the C# developer guidance : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library

Check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions - for different runtime versions.

Also, if you want to call your function as an API, you may create a HttpTrigger function and call that as an API directly or using httpclient object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#example